# Should we allow "Why does God..." type questions?

Tags: discussion, scope, philosophy

Often, questions appear which are asking about God's wisdom behind allowing or forbidding certain things.  While I'm sure there's some fair degree of philosophical study and debate on these, I don't see that such questions are really suitable for this site: Without explicit authoritative proof (e.g. an ayah or hadith explaining exactly the reason), such questions are typically not answerable except with speculation and opinion.

While such questions might be useful if they're scoped to a particular perspective ("Does such-and-such school explain why God does so-and-so?"), even then they would still run the risk of being a [useless negative](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/355/22).

Do such questions have any place on this site at all?  Is there any way to make them constructive, or should they just be closed on sight?

Comment: I find those questions as very dangerous because of this: http://www.kalamullah.com/one.html . Therefore, I think they should be closed.

Comment: @yasar11732 Disagreed. Although I just read the title of the link. It says *"Speaking about Allah without Knowledge"*. Same is the case here on [islam.se] we don't expect anybody to answer until and unless they are knowledgeable enough to do so. And that knowledge is reflected by the logical manner and sources they use to answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

Most such questions can be transformed into: "Are we given a divine wisdom for such-and-such" or "What have the scholars of tafsir said over the centuries when pondering over the wisdom for such-and-such." Both forms are eminently answerable.

Comment: The first one is good "Are we given a divine wisdom for such-and-such"...

Answer (score 2):

Although all of such questions are not answered in Islamic sources. But many of them has answers in Quran and hadith.

For example this verse says the reason why God created human and Jinns:

And I did not create the jinn and mankind except to worship Me. http://tanzil.net/#51:56

This is only one example.

Also there are many hadith from prophet SAWW and Ahl al Bayt explaining the reasons behind Islamic laws.

Also there are some books specifically about the reasons of Islamic laws that have collected different hadith from prophet and Ahl al Bayt about reasons of Islamic laws. For example the book "Ilal al-shara'i (the cause of the situations)" by Shaykh Sadoogh includes the reasons behind the Philosophy of the Islamic laws.

About the questions that we can find the answer from Islamic sources a suitable answer can be provided and the opinion of expert Islamic scholars can be considered proper.

There are at least 5 schools and many sects in Islam. If one does not care about from which sect or school the answer is provided then the question asker should ask a question per each school and sect.

Totally I think such questions can be allowed and proper answer can be provided.