# Please read carefully before approving or rejecting edit suggestions?

Tags: discussion, editing

I've recently come across approved edit suggestion (e.g. [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/5846) and [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/5900)) which either don't improve the post or actually changed it's meaning altogether.

So please be careful with the edits you approve. One is not bound to approve or reject if unsure. [**You can always skip**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/1309352) and let others decide but don't approve improper/meaning changing edits or reject good edits.

Tag edits I personally consider to be minor and lazy because while one's at it they could make other improvement as well, therefore [reject them](https://islam.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/5893). Made an exception [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/5283) because I genuinely thought nothing else could be improved therein.

[This](https://islam.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/5847) edit wasn't entirely necessary and I for one think there is a possibility ("not" isn't always used for negation) that the edit changed the meaning of the title.

If one further edits an edit suggestion and actually uses the suggestions made in that edit that [suggestion](https://islam.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/5130) is definitely [helpful](https://islam.stackexchange.com/revisions/967/5).

More guideline on how to make edits [here](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/952/3487).

I now ask the community to provide there thought and suggestion on this? And provide their disagreements (*if any*) to the guidelines suggested above.

Comment: Can you provide better examples please ? There is a huge difference between "why did yazid kill" and "Did yazid order his soldiers" former gives the impression that Yazid was in the battle and killed Hussien by his own sword. Latter, he gave an order since he was in damascus. and the Um qurfa was a rude move. I opened a meta topic and you ignored it. However, +1 for this post

Comment: See, like you said there is huge difference. Edit are not supposed to be huge differences which could actually risk the meaning and intent of the question. They are meant to improve the post.

Comment: well....You also completely changed the Um Qurfa question and no body complained(OP was asking for something else)... Anyway, It is better if you can find other edits which don't improve a post.

Comment: How was it a rude move? Am I bound to provide answers to every meta discussion? I choose to edit and then answer. Which I did although I wasn't mandated to do either or both. Please *be optimistic*. I fail to see how it *"completely"* changed the question.

Answer (score -1):

I totally agree with you. Unnecessary and simple edits (such as: [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0Z9H.jpg) and [HERE](https://islam.stackexchange.com/posts/12996/revisions)) should be avoided by high rep users and not be approved for low rep users. However, I kindly disagree with you regarding the part "completely changing the meaning".

Often, someone asks a good question that is well formatted and has quality contents. But it doesn't abide with one of the "[Don't ask these questions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)" criteria. (i.e: the 2nd example you gave was implying something which questions should not be used for that).  Thus, In my opinion, the question should be edited , even if this would cause an overhaul change, instead of closing it.  Even the actions of the OP agrees with me when he tried to completely change one of [the questions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/revisions/12780/2). Moreover, you will find a couple of posts (for example [here](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1067/should-we-allow-why-does-god-type-questions)) suggesting some questions to be rephrased because these questions can be answered but they were badly framed.

Comment: The former is a good example and latter is a bad one(it was a good edit, thumbs-up). Secondly this post is about approvals. High-rep user are trusted therefore they are given that right nothing wrong about it. It's their responsibility to make their edit *count* and worthwhile.