# Questions about after life (Akhirah) should be off-topic

Tags: discussion, questions, on-topic

People come and ask if they get to stay with their pets in the after life or will I have 10,000 palaces for me in Jannah and such related questions.  Please avoid those. No one has seen what happens in the after life and everybody is as curious as you are to know how our after life would be.

So, one request to the community, if there are any hadiths which say 'these many no. of palaces will be granted' or 'these many maid servants will be granted' then please cite them here below in the answers.

And please close such fore mentioned questions as these answers consisting hadith and Ayat(verses) below are the only ones which talk about after life. Beyond that, it is a suspense. Please wait and watch as everybody is waiting.

Comment: The amount of down voting that happens in this place is insane. Users, please stop downvoting something simply because its against your belief.

Answer (score 3):

While I understand the concern, I'm not sure I agree with this.  I had brought up a similar issue earlier (see: [Should we allow "Why does God..." type questions?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1067/22)), and while the exact *topic* was different the fundamental rationale behind it was the same: We really have no way of knowing the answer unless there's a clear revelation regarding it.

Such questions *are* readily answerable if and when there *is* a clear revelation regarding it, but otherwise, it's liable to fall into the [useless negative](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/355/22) trap.  The basic *problem* is that one basically needs domain expertise to really know which category it would fall into; it is very difficult to judge such questions otherwise.

Closing as off-topic such questions as a *site* just because they *might* be bad (rather than because, as a domain expert, you *know* they're bad) seems a bit overkill.  Overall, it would probably be better to focus and improve the question so as to attract those who actually *have* domain expertise, and they can deal with it accordingly.