# Why is Islam.SE community so stubborn?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I have posted questions on Hinduism.SE.

Personally, I have a feeling that they are more open and flexible in accepting new questions, and the community is larger as a result.

On the other hand, Islam.SE seems to be extreme and rude. Any questions I am posting are being heavily down-voted and/or critisized.

[image]

The prime examples are the following questions:

1. [Why does islam encourage covering female bodies?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/76510/why-does-islam-encourage-covering-female-bodies)

Even the correct answers are being down-voted.

2. [Why does the holy Q'uran begin with "In the name of Allah , the Compassionate, the Merciful."?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/76579/why-does-the-holy-quran-begin-with-in-the-name-of-allah-the-compassionate-t)

Why is there a difference?

Answer (score 4):

You asked questions. You received criticism on your questions. This isn't "stubborn", or "extreme", or "rude", this is "the system working as intended".

Stack Exchange isn't a dumping ground for any old question; asking a good question — a useful question — is a skill that many questionaskers need to learn. Criticism and negative feedback are tools for this, but the onus is still on the questionasker to ask a good question, not on the community to hold their hand.

Just because one community has higher standards or lower tolerance than another doesn't make them stubborn, it just means that different people in different disciplines have different opinions on what constitutes "useful".

Now, to your questions in particular: Neither of the questions you linked show *any* research effort; on the face of it, it looks like you just read a thing and now you expect us to explain it to you because you were curious. This is just throwing all the effort onto the community to do all the work for you, and I'm not convinced they're [particularly useful to anyone](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1067/22) who is seriously studying the topic of Islam. I didn't downvote either of these questions, but I can easily see why people would.

Instead of blaming the community for your poor reception, why don't you try to put work into your own questions and maybe make them useful for anyone other than yourself? I would suggest exploring the site and paying attention to the questions that *are* well received, and taking your cues from that.

Comment: Can you justify the down-votes on my question? Coz, I haven't understood.

Comment: @user366312 People all downvote for their own reasons, I can't speak for anybody else.

Answer (score 2):

I apologize if you found my comment to be rude. It was on the [first draft](https://islam.stackexchange.com/revisions/76579/1) of your question where you wrote

> "had it been Allah himself, he would not have said (so and so)"

Presenting an opinion as fact. My comment simply challenged this assumption. Criticism is meant to help you understand the flaw in your deduction and to improve the quality of questions on the site ... it should not be taken personally.

Comment: None of these were my own words. All of them were from a Hindu priest's book.

Comment: This post doesn't answer the main question, though.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide evidence of:

*"Personally, I have a feeling that they are more open and flexible in accepting new questions".*

Both of your question are **"Why  This/That".** So you should be prepared for some heat/agression. Finding reason for why in Islam, usually leads to some agression.

For example a guy asked me ["Why is usury haram in Islam?"](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/76633/riba-and-loan-interest/76634?noredirect=1#comment117620_76634), one could comment "because Allah says it's Haram".

You may see comments like "do not question Allah decisions"  or "Who are you to question Allah?". Which on the surface level may seem right as Allah does whatever He wills.

I encountered a similar comment on my first [question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/76541/question-about-quran-230-36) as well but I think I encountered it.

I would not blame the entire community for some mean comments.

Comment: I beg your pardon, but I am looking for an answer from a more experienced user with at least 1k reputation score.

Comment: Wonder what that accomplishes ?

Comment: *Wonder what that accomplishes?* --- He/she will be able to give me a correct insight on the user-behavior in this forum which a less experienced user cannot. Coz, a less experienced user is not familiar enough about this.

Comment: shouldn't this imply both ways but you based a whole opinion on the Islamic community with less than 1k rep.

Comment: *shouldn't this imply both ways but you based a whole opinion on the Islamic community with less than 1k rep.* --- No. Coz, I have been using SE for the last 12 years or more. I was forced to delete my profile several times and recreate it in Islam.SE because of negative voting.

Comment: You sure are stubborn enough to return.

Comment: Yes, coz, I have some questions to ask.