# Can I ask this question about an Islamic studies-related university program?

Tags: discussion

After reading the Help pages, I'm not certain if this question would be on topic.

I am interested in taking some courses through an online university. The program is an Arabic Studies program offered online from a predominantly Muslim country.  Unfortunately I can't tell whether the university is legitimate or not. I don't have any special reason to be skeptical, except that the price is extremely low. This could be for many legitimate reasons.

I think this *may* be a good fit for Islam.SE for a couple reasons based on the "What topics can i ask about here" page:

- This stack is open to "those interested in Islam on an academic level." I certainly match that description, and I hope that others in the same category would be able to answer my question.
- This question does not fall into any of the prohibited categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems borderline to me.  Some problems that might arise:

- It may be closed as "primarily opinion-based".  It sounds like the intended question is asking for a review of the course.  Carefully wording the question might alleviate this, e.g., asking if there's any specific "red flags" about the particular course.
- It's a very specific request---would it be of use to others?
- It may incur a reverse of [the "useless negative" problem](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355/the-useless-negative-problem)---if the answer is "it's fine", how can an answerer demonstrate that?

A better approach may be to ask a general question, e.g. something like:

*Is an extremely low price a red flag that an online Islamic studies-related university program is poor?*

or

*Are online Islamic studies-related university programs ordinarily inexpensive?*

The specific example can be the motivation for the question.  It's still opinion-based (so still may end up closed), but this way it would be more amenable to a non-opinion-based answer.